# How to assign null value in datetime field

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have tried:

```
CAST(NULL AS DATETIME) AS Exit_T.
```

Give me the following error:

> *The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.*

Are we able to assign null values to `DateTime` fields? I need this after query hit some conditions

Comment: Also: `DATETIME` in SQL Server has a value range of 1/1/1753 to 12/31/9999 - but `NULL` might be interpreted as 0/0/0000 - therefore it cannot convert it. Try using `DATETIME2` or just plain `DATE` if you're on SQL Server **2008** or newer (you didn't specify the version you're using).

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do? You don't typically use NULL in a cast. You would assign the keyword NULL to the value of the field. Nulls are acceptable in DateTime fields if you allow it.

Comment: How can i allow null in my above statement? i am using the select ... into T1 From O_table

Comment: @10e5x: Could you show (in the question) the *complete* statement that produced the error? The involved tables' schemas would also be most helpful.

Comment: Make sure your destination table allows nulls in the DateTime column. Use 'SELECT * FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS' and check the attribute 'IS_NULLABLE'. If your sorce and destination tables contain DateTime columns there is no need to cast anything.

Answer (score 1):

If `datetime` field is a `NULL`-able field, we can assign the `NULL` values, otherwise, we *can't* able to assign the `NULL` values.

See how the issue is *not* the cast, but must rather come from elsewhere:

```
select CASE(NULL AS DATETIME) AS Exit_T;
```